# Landsat 8 data with keras autoencoder

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, autoencoder

I am trying to input a 7 band .tif image to a keras input layer.

```
input_img = Input(shape=(246, 177, 7))
```

The tif image is 246 x 177 and has 7 bands.

I am using rasterio to read the image as follows:

```
with rio.open(landsat_post_fire_path) as src:
    landsat_post_fire = src.read()
```

This gives me 7 arrays of shape 177, 246

Since i have only one image, I am inserting it into an array:

```
x_train = np.expand_dims(landsat_post_fire, axis=0)
```

My complete autoencoder looks as follows:

```
input_size = 43542 #246 x 177
hidden_size = 20000
code_size = 5000

input_img = Input(shape=(246, 177, 7))
hidden_1 = Dense(hidden_size, activation='relu')(input_img)
code = Dense(code_size, activation='relu', activity_regularizer=l1(10e-6))(hidden_1)
hidden_3 = Dense(hidden_size, activation='relu')(code)
output_img = Dense(input_size, activation='sigmoid')(hidden_3)

autoencoder = Model(input_img, output_img)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')
autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train, epochs=1)
```

When I finally run the code, I get the following error:

```
Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have shape (246, 177, 7) but got array with shape (7, 177, 246)
```

Am I missing how the input shape is working?
I don't understand what seems to be the issue here. I would be grateful if someone can help explaining how the Input understands the dimension.

**EDIT**
I added the following line after reading the image:
landsat_post_fire=np.moveaxis(landsat_post_fire,0,-1)

But now the error is:
Error when checking target: expected dense_4 to have shape (177, 246, 43542) but got array with shape (177, 246, 7)

I think this is not the right way to tell the input about the number of bands in the image?

Comment: The issue is that (246, 177, 7) is not the same as (7, 177, 246), you need to provide data in the exact same input shape you told Keras.

Comment: I tried fixing this issue with landsat_post_fire=np.moveaxis(landsat_post_fire,0,-1). but I think the problem is with the actual band number, not with the dimension. Now the error is: 

Error when checking target: expected dense_4 to have shape (177, 246, 43542) but got array with shape (177, 246, 7)